# textbox in php value not outputting spaces

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a textbox in HTML that I need to set its value. Upon loading the modal (twitterbootstrap) the textbox should have its predefined value.

I'm having trouble in outputting the value from php.

I have this code:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  
name="inputBirthdate" id="datepicker" 
value=<?php echo $displayBdate; ?> required>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <script src="pikaday.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            var picker = new Pikaday(
                            {
                                field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
                                firstDay: 1,
                                minDate: new Date('1980-01-01'),
                                maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
                                yearRange: [1980,2020]
                            });
                        </script>
```

The variable `$displayBdate` has the value string: "Sat Oct 18 2014". When I try checking the value of that variable by using the `die($displayBdate)`, it outputs exactly as "Sat Oct 18 2014".

Now, what I'm getting really is only "Sat". Also, when I try `value=<?php echo 'WAT DA F'; ?>` the textbox has only "WAT". It means the error starts from the first space. help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the PHP value inside quotation marks.

Change this...

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"
name="inputBirthdate" id="datepicker"
value=<?php echo $displayBdate; ?> required>
```

...into this...

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"
name="inputBirthdate" id="datepicker"
value="<?php echo $displayBdate; ?>" required>
```

Comment: HEY!!! Thank you first for editing my qquestion. I was very sleepy when I typed that. And thank you for the great answer! It solved the f mystery XD. thank you sir! Imagine, I was debugging my code for almost 2 hours, and the answer is just two quotations.

Comment: you're very welcome... yeah, sometimes those little annoying characters can throw it all off... ;)